# Ionic drop-down display on wrong position when keyboard hide

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing one application in ionic. Working good but issue occurs in iPad and Tablet only.

**Issue:** In the app there is one form and in that form, there is one TextField that have display selection box *(like dropdown)*. It's working good but If we are on another TextField and Keyboard is open and click on that drop-down then the keyboard is hidden but drop-down position stuck in the middle actual it should on that particular TextField.

I tried to solve this problem last 3 days but can't able to find a solution.

**Note:** We are using `HTML` select options tag like below.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If you want more elaborate then please tell me.